# Using INSERT INTO with WHERE

Tags: sql

I have a table `Id | DocId | Page | WordCount`

I want to insert the word counts for N pages. That is if N=3 then I want to add all the WordCount for pages 1,2 and 3 and then insert them into a new table `Id | DocId | WordCount`

I am trying to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO [NewDocTable] (DocId, WordCount)
    SELECT [W].DocId AS DocId, SUM ([W].WordCount) AS WordCount
    FROM [OldDocTable] AS [W]
    WHERE [W].Page <= @N
```

Could someone help?

I have the following the error: Column 'OldDocTable.DocId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ok, but what is the problem exactly?

Comment: And that error message, or especially the last part of it, doesn't give you a *hint* at a way to fix it?

Comment: The error message gives you a pretty good indicator of what's wrong. That select statement is doing aggregation (the SUM) so you need to add a group by statement for that to work. adding GROUP BY [W].DocId to the end should fix the issue

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Tried adding a group by? The fact that you are using a summarization function `SUM()` in this case, will require you to tell the database that you want to sum them up against the `DocId`

```
INSERT INTO [NewDocTable] (DocId, WordCount)
    SELECT [W].DocId AS DocId, SUM ([W].WordCount) AS WordCount
    FROM [OldDocTable] AS [W]
    WHERE [W].Page <= @N
    GROUP BY [W].DocId
```

Comment: Still the same error :( Am I missing some parenthesis, tabs or something?

Comment: Does the `SELECT` statement run by itself (with out the insert part?)

Comment: Good to know that!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very clear from your error message. Use the below query:

```
INSERT INTO [NewDocTable] (DocId, WordCount)
    SELECT [W].DocId AS DocId, SUM ([W].WordCount) AS WordCount
    FROM [OldDocTable] AS [W]
    WHERE [W].Page <= @N
    GROUP BY [W].DocId
```

Check [this.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: As [W].WordCount is part of an aggregate then you wouldn't want this in the group by.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the group by that the statement suggests;

```
INSERT INTO [NewDocTable] (DocId, WordCount)
SELECT [W].DocId AS DocId, SUM ([W].WordCount) AS WordCount
FROM [OldDocTable] AS [W]
WHERE [W].Page <= @N
GROUP BY [W].DocId
```

The issue isn't with the INSERT INTO, it's with your SELECT statement. To check that it's doing what you're expecting it's always good practice to run the select on it's own first to ensure it is working.